# Convert part of the following chef recipe to Ansible

Tags: chef-infra, ansible

I am trying to convert following chef recipe into Ansible. What could be the equivalent of it ?.. I am familiar with Ansible. Is it correct that there are going to be three directories created ?. Such as /usr/share/agentone/lib ; /usr/share/agentone/etc ; /usr/share/agentone/bin and all of them have the 0755 mode on ?

```
 if node[:platform_family] == 'debian'

  %w{lib etc bin}.each do |dir|
    directory "/usr/share/agentone/#{dir}" do
     mode '0755'
     owner 'root'
     group 'root'
     action :create
     recursive true
    end
  end

  directory '/var/log/agentone'
  directory 'var/run/agentone'

  link '/usr/share/agentone/logs' do
   to '/var/log/agentone'
  end

  template '/etc/init.d/agentone' do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '750'
    source 'agentone.init.erb'
    variables(
      :version => node[:base][:agent][:agent_artifact][:version]
     )
  end

 end
```

What could be the best way to write in Ansible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ansible version of this would be something like this:

```
- name: create dirs
  file: path=/usr/share/agentone/{{ item }}
        state=directory
        owner=root
        group=root
        mode=0755
        recurse=true
  with_items:
      - lib
      - etc
      - bin
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Debian'
```

Edit: With respect to the additional code you added:

```
- name: symlink /usr/share/agentone/logs
  file: path=/usr/share/agentone/logs
        src=/var/log/agentone
        state=link

- name: template /etc/init.d/agentone
  template: src=agentone.init.erb
            dest=/etc/init.d/agentone
            owner=root
            group=root
            mode=0750
```

With respect to the variables used in the template task, they just need to be added to your inventory file, a vars file, or anywhere else [Ansible variables can be defined](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Comment: Hey Bruce. I have added some more config, could you help me out in converting those in Ansible ?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. The 2 directories in the chef file mentioned is the same as following:     - name: create dirs
                      file: path=/var/log/agentone
                             state=directory

                    - name: create dirs
                      file: path=var/run/agentone
                      state=directory                                                                                      Correct ?

Comment: Here the entire config is under the ansible family distribution in debian. How can I mention the entire configuration under "debian" family ? Should I add that line at the last or Do I need to mention it after each configuration ?